# Embedding maps using Qt Quick

Tags: android, maps, qtquick2

I want to know if it's possible to embed any map service in a QML App for Android.

I checked [Google maps for Android Qt 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732288/qt-5-2-or-5-3rc-android-app-development-and-google-maps-usage) and it indicates it's not possible to get Google Maps working on Android with a WebView object as it was in development.

I want to know if there're any alternatives or if anything has changed with the 5.3 release.
Any way I can embed any maps services on a tablet?

I'm using the Galaxy Tab 2.7.0 P3110 and Qt 5.3 width Qt Quick 2.